How to activate handles to edit curves in Grease Pencil 3.0 - Blender 4.3?
In previeous versions we had this option when we wanted to edit curves with bezier handles.

Now, I'm using Blende 4.3, Grease Pencil 3.0, and noticed that we don't have this option anymore.

After searchig fora solution I found there is this option STROKE > SET CURVE TYPE > BÉZIER, that is supposed to be what I need, basically where the "Curve Editing" thing was moved to.

The problem is that when I click it after selecting a curve nothing changes in the curve I have selected. The curves remained the same as they were before I click in tat option.
Am I doing something wrong, maybe a step I keep missing or it's just a bug?

I think you have a lot of points, meaning the handles of each point are very small. I don't know if there is a way to resample the curve.

This is probably the case, but there is no way to resample the curve maintaining the shape it's a huge set back comparing to the previous versions, because in then just by clicking on Curve Editing I would give me only 2 or 3 ponts to manipulate in a stroke like this.

In 4.3 Grease pencil has been rewritted, I heard somewhere that this function will be rebuilt as soon as possible.

As you have probably noticed, Curve Edit Mode has been discontinued and has thus been replaced by the Curve Type of strokes.
In Edit Mode with Select Mode set to Point, select the points/lines that you want to convert to Bézier. Then go to Stroke $\rightarrow$ Set Curve Type $\rightarrow$ Bézier

You'll notice that more points have been added to your line(s). Now, go to Point $\rightarrow$ Set Handle Type $\rightarrow$ Align

This is the closest I could get a curve to behave like a Bézier curve from the old Curve Edit Mode.

If your GP curve has too many points to edit, then the only workaround I found was to zoom, Zoom, ZOOM, and ZOOOOOOM into the point that you want to edit.
Here is the manual for more information.
